# Using a range of excel value as conditions in a SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a macro that queries the SQL database but enters a condition into the query.  That condition is a range of values in a column in the spreadsheet.

So, I have "Sheet1", where column A is titled "code" with values from A2 onwards.  I want to run a SQL query that says:

```
SELECT value FROM dbtable WHERE code = 'ValueFromA2'
```

With the result being populated in cell B2.

I then need to continue that query down through B3, B4, etc. until it's reached the end of the range of values in column A.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Excel to create list of queries into the new column by concatenating your SQL logic with "code" values.

   See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819629/327165
2. Use VBA to loop thru column with SQL queries and populate results into column B. 
   As an option you can create queries in VBA.

   See this example: [SQL query in VBA, code stored in several cells in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45193810/327165)